# Visual studio:Side by side error for debug x64 build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, winsxs

I have a fresh installation for VS 2008 and I made sure to check the "x64 compiler and tools" during installation. But when I make a x64 debug build of an exe , that gives a side-by-side error when attempting to run. The eventviewer logs the following:

```
"Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."
```

sxstrace shows the following :

```
INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\Work\SPR5569_Tools_modification\Configutil\ProfilePush\debug\x64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\Work\SPR5569_Tools_modification\Configutil\ProfilePush\debug\x64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\Work\SPR5569_Tools_modification\Configutil\ProfilePush\debug\x64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at D:\Work\SPR5569_Tools_modification\Configutil\ProfilePush\debug\x64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
INFO: End assembly probing.
```

My question is :

1- "INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS." Why was the assembly not added to WinSxS by the installer?

2- The file can be found in the `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT"` location. Why is the installer installing it here when it would not be used from here?

3- I managed to get the program working by taking the files from above location and putting it alongside the executable. But what is the correct way to resolve this situation?

4- Whose issue is this ? Is this the VS setup which is not proper?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The VS2008 installer is certainly supposed to install that DLL into the c:\windows\winsxs side-by-side assembly cache.  Why this didn't happen is impossible to guess.  Review the installer log files for hints.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant. Are you talking of setupapi.log?